# Custom Base Adapter to ListView

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, baseadapter, getview

I have tried so many different tutorials trying to get it work I'm wondering if something is wrong with my machine..
This is my MainActivity where I create myadapter and set it to the ListView.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

UserRepo userRepo;
ArrayList<user> userList;
ListView list;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    userRepo = new UserRepo();
    userList = userRepo.getUserArrayList();
    UserAdapter myadapter = new UserAdapter(this, userList );
    list.setAdapter(myadapter);
}

}
```

This is my custom user class.

```
public class user {

String name;
String description;


public user(String name, String description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
}
```

This is my custom UserAdapter. I have tried so many different versions of this from so many different tutorials and no matter what I do I can't get it to work with the ArrayList that I'm passing it.

```
public class UserAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


ArrayList<user> list;
Context context;
LayoutInflater mInflater;

public UserAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<user> list)
{
    context = c;
    this.list = list;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    } else {
        mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    user currentListData = (user) getItem(position);

    mViewHolder.tv_name.setText(currentListData.getName());
    mViewHolder.tv_description.setText(currentListData.getDescription());


    return convertView;
}

private class MyViewHolder {
    TextView tv_name, tv_description;


    public MyViewHolder(View item) {
        tv_name = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tv_description = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tv_description);

    }
}
}
```

This is my UserRepo where I create the ArrayList and have a method that I can use to create it and return one.

```
public class UserRepo {
ArrayList<user> list;

public ArrayList<user> getUserArrayList(){
    user john = new user("John", "Samoan Flatmate");
    list.add(john);
    user ariki = new user ("Ariki", "Māori Flatmate");
    list.add(ariki);
    user dion = new user ("Dion", "Asian Flatemate");
    list.add(dion);

    return list;
}
}
```

This is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.petakirikiri.customlistview">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: You never say what the actual problem is! Is the app crashing? If so please add the stack trace from logcat. One thing that looks off initially is I do not see where you are assigning `ArrayList<user> list` to a new instance of an `ArrayList` in the `UserRepo`.

Comment: Yeah it does crash sorry, I can't tell what I means on my logcat.  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                           at com.example.petakirikiri.customlistview.UserRepo.getUserArrayList(UserRepo.java:13)
                                                                                           at com.example.petakirikiri.customlistview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)

Comment: Thank you George Mulligan you were right. Big help I've been here for the last two days pulling my hair out. Guess this is all part of the journey...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `UserRepo` class you never initialize `ArrayList<user> list`. Change the code to initialize it.

```
public class UserRepo {
    ArrayList<user> list = new ArrayList<>();
    // The rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you again for your time. This has been destroying me for two days and it was just that simple line of code :(

Comment: You're welcome. As you become more experienced you'll know exactly what that stack trace is trying to tell you and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an instance of an ArrayList

```
public class UserRepo {
    ArrayList<user> list;

    public ArrayList<user> getUserArrayList(){
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    user john = new user("John", "Samoan Flatmate");
    list.add(john);
    user ariki = new user ("Ariki", "Māori Flatmate");
    list.add(ariki);
    user dion = new user ("Dion", "Asian Flatemate");
    list.add(dion);

    return list;
  }
}
```